# Is it possible to show all products from collection.template?

Tags: templates, collections, shopify, liquid

I hope someone could help with this...
Is it possible to show all products from another collection template? So, this is regular "call": `collections.all.url`. And I'm trying to achieve something like this `collections.wholesale.all.url`. Of course, that's not the right way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you know the handle of the collection you want, do:

```
{% for p in collections['YOUR_HANDLE_HERE'].products %}
    {{ p.title }}
    {{ p.price | money }}
    .... etc
{% endfor %}
```

You can not get collections by the template they are using, regardless of the amount of collections using a template. you can **ONLY** retrieve an individual collection by it's handle.

**{{ collections['YOUR_HANDLE_HERE'] | json }}**

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My problem here is that I want to show all products from collection template, without manually making a specific collection that contains all the products. So collections.all.url is a link for all of my products for B2C, and I have completely different products and different design for B2B, that's why I'm making another template.

Comment: You could do a GET call to the collection url then get the html from the response and append it to you body.